# How can I drop rows in a time series dataframe based on conditioning the time in the timestamp. i.e dropping rows for a particular time of the day

Tags: python, datetime, filter, time-series, timestamp

[image: Timestamp_UTC is the datetime index]

[image]

[image]

I have data of 7 months on an hourly and minutes basis. I want to drop night time data (7:30pm to 5:10am) from everyday.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a datetime as index, you don't need to use **dt**. Also, **dt.hour** returns an integer value. But you are using an integer value with a string expression. You can use like this:

```
df2=df.loc[(df.index.hour >= 5) & (df.index.hour <= 19)]
```

but there is simple way. Use [between_time()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
df=df.between_time('05:10:00', '19:30:00')
```